# Clojure spec coerce nested map value

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I coerce a map value like so:

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(defn x-integer? [x]
  (cond
    (integer? x) x
    (string? x) (try
                  (Integer/parseInt x)
                  (catch Exception e
                    :clojure.spec/invalid))
    :else :clojure.spec/invalid))

(s/def ::port (s/conformer x-integer?))

(s/def ::config (s/keys :req [::port]))

(s/conform ::config {::port "12345"}) ;;=> #:my.ns{:port "12345"}
```

However I do not see how I could do the same with the following map instead :

```
(s/conform ::config {::nested-data {:port "12345"}}) ;;=> something like that maybe ? #:my.ns/nested-data{:port 12345}
```

How should `::config` be defined ? Also, would it be preferable to have `{::nested-data {::port "12345"}}` instead ?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a ::port spec that uses x-integer? This example seems incomplete.

Comment: @AlexMiller you are right, question edited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(s/def ::port (s/conformer x-integer?))
(s/def ::nested-data (s/keys :req-un [::port]))
(s/def ::config (s/keys :req [::nested-data]))
(s/conform ::config {::nested-data {:port "12345"}})
;;=> #:spec.examples.guide{:nested-data {:port 12345}}
```